# Panda DF : Find minimum in multiple columns with condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, min

In a pandas dataframe, I am trying to find the minimum of different columns that respects a condition in an other column (kind of an SQL WHERE)

```
MIN = (dataframe[['col_1','col_2','col_3', 'col_4']].min().min())
```

But i want MIN to be calculated only where `'col_5' == 'YES'`

I have tried to find in the forum but i am not managing to merge the 'multiple column min' and the 'conditional min'..

Thank you !

Comment: Please create some mock data so, we can provide you with a verifiable solution.

Comment: `dataframe[dataframe['col_5']='YES'].min().min()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you want something like

```
MIN = dataframe[dataframe['col_5'] == 'YES']['col_1','col_2','col_3', 'col_4'].min().min()
```

or a more readable version

```
dataframe_yes = dataframe[dataframe['col_5'] == 'YES']
MIN = dataframe_yes[['col_1','col_2','col_3', 'col_4']].min().min()
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for !